# How to get AutoMapper definitions by (source,destination) pair?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

In AutoMapper, we can use projection to customise the mapping like this:

```
public class CalendarEventForm
{
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public int EventHour { get; set; }
    public int EventMinute { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class CalendarEventForm
{
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public int EventHour { get; set; }
    public int EventMinute { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Configure AutoMapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CalendarEvent, CalendarEventForm>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.EventDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.Date))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.EventHour, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.Hour))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.EventMinute, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.Minute));
```

Is there any available API that we can use to get the mapping logic conversely, by provding the `(source,destination)` pair?

Comment: you don't have to do that with automapper, the whole point of using automapper is that it figures all that out on its own.  The custom mapping is for when either types or names don't match

Comment: could you say what is the aim of this?

Comment: @Kirill Bestemyanov i want to use the INotifyPropertyChanged  to hook the source and destination dynamically,however,the changed property of source is unpredictable